# Is there a way to return word cloud into string or character data type?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, word-cloud

I am using `library(wordcloud)` to make a word cloud in r. However I am more interested in the actual words as a string type that I can later use in an excel cell. Is there any way that I can make wordcloud in r return a string, rather than making a wordcloud object?

This is my function implementation:

```
create_wordcloud <- function(text)  {
  corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text)
  w_cloud <- wordcloud(corpus, min.freq = 1,
            max.words=50, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, 
            colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
  return(corpus) #I need this to be a string 
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some example data and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the Corpus to a `data.frame` and reshape it with `reshape2`'s `melt()` function.

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(reshape2)

create_wordcloud <- function(text)  {
    corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text)
    wordcloud(corpus, min.freq = 1,
        max.words=50, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, 
        colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
    word_matrix <- as.matrix(DocumentTermMatrix(corpus))
    word_matrix_df <- as.data.frame(word_matrix)
    word_matrix_df <- melt(word_matrix_df, variable.name = 'word', value.name = 'frequency')

    return(word_matrix_df)
}
```

This returns a `data.frame` with in its columns the words and their frequency in the text. If you are fine with a `matrix` structure, you can skip the `data.frame` and `reshape2::melt()` step.